# A question about electric field

Tags: electric-fields, potential, conventions

I would like to understand why is it the charge density while dealing with currents is $\mathop{\mathrm{div}}(E)/4\pi$, while when dealing with insulators is $-\mathop{\mathrm{div}}(E)/4\pi$?

Thank you very much, and sorry if it's too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vacuum (or everywhere else, really), Coulomb's law takes the form  $\boldsymbol\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$, whereas in a polarizable material it is convenient to use $\boldsymbol\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \rho_\mathrm{free}$.

The $4\pi$ vs $\epsilon$ has more to do with units. As for the sign, can you give a reference?

Comment: Yes. As a beginner, I was told that Gauss's Law tells us that the Divergence of the Electric field equals $-4πρ$(So the Laplacian is $-4πρ$ as well). While here we witness the opposite (as you just mentioned above). Thanks for the replay.

Comment: I think the point is that $\mathbf{E} = -\boldsymbol{\nabla} \Phi$, which is probably where your sign confusion is coming from.